# How to display placeholder text on focus?

Tags: javascript, html, input, focus, placeholder

I have the following placeholder:

```
 <div class="input-text-container search" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" id="textSearch" class="input-text-big search-message" placeholder="Search in your list"/>
    <i class="common-sprite cross search"></i>
</div>
```

The input is displayed when the user clicks on an icon with the class "search.icon-search"

I use the following JS code:

```
 $('.search.icon-search').on(
        'click',
        function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
         $('#textSearch').focus()
        });
```

The problem is that the placeholder disappears on focus. How can I display it even on focus?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574356/html5-placeholder-disappears-on-focus

Comment: @saty That's not the answer. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show `.input-text-container`, but your code works.

Try this:

```
$('.search.icon-search').on('click',function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(".input-text-container").show();            
     $('#textSearch').focus()
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/3zkpgvj5/**

Comment: @For some reason the "$(".input-text-container").show()" doesn't work

Comment: Works in Chrome and Firefox and not in IE11

Comment: Maybe because of this reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969959/jquery-hide-show-code-not-working-in-internet-explorer

Comment: @ Radonirina Maminiaina- I guess there is another function which remove the placeholder. So I just add " $('#textSearch').attr('placeholder','Search in your list')", and it works

Comment: @SaritSara Were you able to check my code, which doesn't require any JavaScript and it is fast and easy too? Just asking... You don't need such JavaScripts for a small thing. Your browser will be loaded heavily.

Comment: @ Praveen Kumar- as I wrote I guess another function remove the placeholder.... so your code also didn't work for me

Comment: here why you are adding e.preventDefault();?

Comment: Is this works in IE11 .? i don't see it works in IE browser.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need any JavaScript or jQuery for this. I have a **pure CSS** solution. You can use an opacity on `focus`.

```css
input {opacity: 0; outline: 0; border: 0;}
input:focus {opacity: 1; outline: 0; border: 0;}
span {border: 1px solid #999; display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<span><input placeholder="This is not visible until you click!" /></span>
```

Comment: Good light weight CSS solution

Comment: In my opinion it's not pure if you need to alter your html and put span around your inputs.

Comment: Is this works in IE11 .? i don't see it works in IE browser.

Comment: @krish I don't think placeholder is yet supported in IE 11. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522164.

Answer (score 3):

```
input::placeholder{
    opacity: 0;
}

input:focus::placeholder{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code-only answers are discouraged as they provide no insight into how the problem was solved. Please update your answer to include an explanation of how your code solves the OP's problem :)

Comment: I think this was great and concise, because it's one of the rare situations where all the CSS properties are self-explanatory. Perhaps the pseudoelements is the most advanced part of the code, so I can see a point in providing a link for readers to read about that.